# Including a file without overwriting property variables

Tags: xml, ant, build.xml

My understanding after [reading the snippet on the include vs import task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html) was that using an `import` would override a target's function, and using `include` would mean you'd have to use a prepended version of the target to get the included version's behavior. My end goal is to not necessarily targets, but instead to import/include a property value from another build.xml file. I created these two build.xml files to attempt to illustrate to myself how it would work.

My first one, dog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="dog">

    <include as="corgi" file="corgi.xml" />

    <property name="breed" value="mutt" />
    <property name ="bark" value="woof"/>

    <target name="nameit">
        <echo>This dog is a ${breed}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="startBarking">
        <echo>${bark}, ${bark}, ${bark}!</echo>
    </target>   

</project>
```

and the build.xml I'm wanting to include, corgi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="corgi">

    <property name="breed" value="corgi" />
    <property name="bark" value="bow-wow" />

    <target name="nameit">
        <echo>This dog is a ${breed}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="startBarking">
        <echo>${bark}, ${bark}, ${bark}!</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Given that I am using an include, I am expecting to get a "mutt" that "woofs" when I run the targets that belong to dog.xml, but instead the corgi.xml is overriding the file, and I am getting a "corgi" that says "bow-wow" regardless of whether or not I use `include` or `import`. What's going on here, and how could I include the corgi.xml file while still having access to dog.xml's properties?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because properties are immutable as I seemed to miss; when you set them the first time, they cannot be changed. As per the documentation on properties:

> Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.

So to get the behavior of dog.xml, as long as the dog.xml properties are set before corgi.xml is brought in, you will get the dog.xml version of those properties.